# Is it possible to track source styles definition (sass, scss) in Vue while developing?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to import styles from external libraries and still keep original reference to it's original library name.

In classic HTML I would create a `<style>` to minified `css` in `index.html`, but I need to make customizations and so I must use those library's source `scss`, i.e [Bulma](https://bulma.io).

I need this so I can keep using Chrome's developer tools and see from where the inspected element's styles are coming from and change it at the source or override if needs to be.

Example:

app.vue:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "styles/app.scss";
</style>
```

app.scss:

```
@charset "utf-8";

// Import Bulma's core
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";

// Custom
@import "variables";

// Import Bulma and Buefy styles
@import "~bulma";
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";

// Mixed overrides
@import "overrides";
```

When inspecting an element in Chrome's developer tool, I can see its styles coming from vue's injected styles, even though it's coming originally from a library definitions.
For example Bulma's navbar border-radius appears in styles and not from some sort of a "navbar.sass":

[image: navbar's border-radius appears in styles]

In such a case I knew exactly where that style was coming from, but my workflow will get harder as I add more CSS styles.

**How can I use other libraries source scss files and keep having a reference to original style location?**

Eventually, of course, I would like to have a single css file for my app.

(I'm using vue-cli 3)

Comment: You will want to enable source maps.  https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-sourcemap

Comment: It did it! Thanks! 
You should answer the question properly so I can mark it so.

Answer (score 3):

Use sourceMap: true in vue.config.js like below,

```
module.exports = {
  css: {    
    sourceMap: true
  }
}
```

I am using it like below,

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/assets/styles/style.scss";`
      }
    },
    sourceMap: true
  }
}
```